# Invoke OnKeyUp by JS from browser URL line

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following script in a form:

```
onkeyup="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'return callSearchPlz(this.value);','mojarra.ab(this,event ,\'keyup\',0,\'landingForm:lp-postal landingForm:lp-ort landingForm:lp-postal-text\')')"
```

How can I invoke a `onkeyup` event there?
I want to do that from the browser URL line.